# Why doesn't this sequence of keys, using SyRq, work

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, reboot, crash

I have Fedora 20, with zshell and Mate desktop. I have just come across this [article about using SysRq  keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key), but they don't give the results shown there. I am using Alt with the key marked "Home" with "Print Scr" above it as the SysRq key combination.

I have also tried holding the yellow "FN" key as well, but this made no difference.

Since the  "Reboot Even If System Utterly Broken" sequence looks very useful, I would please like to know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally when you press a button, the keyboard generates a single keycode. The OS receives keycodes, applies some key mapping, and tries to handle key combinations independently of the underlying hardware.

The SysRq mechanism is a little bit different:
The keyboard catches the combination and sends a special keycode to the OS as if the single button was pressed. The Linux kerenel catches the special keycode and handles it internally without forwarding the input to higher-level applications like the X server.
That implies the two consequences:

1. The key combination really depends on the keyboard. The keyboard must catch the key all pressings on its own and only the keyboard "knows" where the actual SysRq key is located and which combination triggers sending the special keycode. So:

   - The SysRq is not necessarily located on the same button as "Home" or "Print Screen", try to search it, usually it is marked explicitly as "SysRq".
   - Try different combinations: `Ctrl+Alt+SysRq+b`  or  `Ctrl+Alt+Fn+SysRq+b`, etc (warning, the system will reboot on success). On keyboards that have the `Fn` key you usually have to press it to reach the actual `SysRq` key, so likely your combination will involve the `Fn` key.
2. You actually can know when you get the combination right. Run `xev` from a terminal, focus the `xev`'s window and hit some buttons on the keyboard, you should see events appeared in the terminal. When you get a right combination, you should NOT get an event because it is caught by the kernel and not delivered to the X server.

Also refer to the documentation: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysrq.txt

Comment: I would like to accept both answers, but unfortunately that is not allowed Thank you both, very useful information.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have SysRq combinations disabled. There are a few things that must be true for this to work:

- You must have `CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ` enabled in your kernel configuration.
- You must have the `kernel.sysrq` sysctl set to a value that enables interpreting SysRq combinations.

`kernel.sysrq` is a bitmask to enable/disable functions:

- 0 - Completely disabled
- 1 - Completely enabled
- 2 - Allow controlling console logging level
- 4 - Allow controlling keyboard
- 8 - Allow controlling process dumps
- 16 - Allow controlling `sync()` calls
- 32 - Allow remounting read-only
- 64 - Allow process signalling
- 128 - Allow altering system power state (reboot/power off/etc)
- 256 - Allow renicing tasks running realtime

Assuming you want to enable all SysRq features, you can set the value temporarily using the `sysctl` tool:

```
sysctl -w kernel.sysrq=1
```

To do this permanently, add the following line to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
kernel.sysrq = 1
```

You can then have the system reload the settings in `/etc/sysctl.conf` by issuing `sysctl -p`.